# Interpretation of the entropic relaxation of the optimal transport problem

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization, transportation

For two probabilities vector $r,c\in \mathbb{R}^k$, the optimal transport is to find the joint distribution of $r,c$ such that it
$$\min_{T\in P} \langle T,C \rangle\\P\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times x},\text{which is the joint distribution}$$

For a variety of reasons, finding the solution is computationally hard. Hence, on page 3 of the paper [Sinkhorn Distances:
Lightspeed Computation of Optimal Transport (2013)](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2013/file/af21d0c97db2e27e13572cbf59eb343d-Paper.pdf) by Marco Cuturi is introduced a subset of the set of all possible joint distributions. However, I find it hard to understand how this new set is a subset of all possible joint distributions.

First, the set $U(r,c) = \{P\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times x} | P\vec{1} = r,P^T\vec{1} = c \}$ contains all possible joint distribution. My understanding is that any matrix that gives $r$ and $c$ as its marginals is a valid joint distribution for $r,c$. Let us denote these two conditions as $\gamma$.

The subset that is introduced by that paper is simply:
$U_\alpha(r,c) = \{P\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times x} | h(P) \ge h(r) + h(c) - \alpha\}, h(.)$ is the entropy. My main question is how does $h(P) \ge h(r) + h(c) - \alpha$ guarantee the two conditions denoted by $\gamma$? The other below questions were raised while me trying to answer this question.

The paper started by stating the entropy of the joint is less than the sum of the entropy of its marginals, which is understood $h(P) \le h(r) + h(c)$. Then they carried on and said that the outer product of the entropy of the two distributions $h(rc^T) = h(r) + h(c)$, so what does it mean to have an outer product of two distributions?

Then, before they reach the final definition of the subset, they first defined the subset as:

$U_\alpha(r,c) = \{P\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times x} | KL(P||rc^T) < \alpha\}$,
where I am not sure how  $KL(P||rc^T) < \alpha$ is related to the $\gamma$ conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost half a year late, but here goes anyway :

- Regarding your first and third question, all the answers are in the first paragraph of page 3 of the paper you refer to (I guess you just misread it ?) : you wrote

> The subset that is introduced by that paper is simply: $U_\alpha(r,c) = \{P\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times x} | h(P) \ge h(r) + h(c) - \alpha\}$

But that is not true. If you look again, the subset $U_\alpha(r,c)$ is rather defined as

$$U_\alpha(r,c) := \{P\in\color{red}{U(r,c)}\mid  KL(P||rc^T) \le \alpha\} \equiv U_\alpha^{KL}(r,c)$$

Which the author claims (and proves) is **equal** to :

$$\{P\in\color{red}{U(r,c)}\mid  h(P) \ge h(r) + h(c) - \alpha\}\equiv U_\alpha^h(r,c) $$

Hence, the answer to your first question is simply that the set $U_\alpha(r,c)$ is *defined* as a set of elements of $U(r,c)$ satisfying some extra condition, so necessarily $U_\alpha(r,c)\subseteq U(r,c)$. You are right however that the inequality constraint on the entropy of $P$ does not imply anything on the marginals.

You asked about the relationship between the KL inequality constraint and the $\gamma$ conditions : as we've seen, $U_\alpha^{KL}(r,c) = U_\alpha^{h}(r,c)$, i.e. the KL inequality constraint is *equivalent* to the entropy inequality constraint (if you're not sure why, prove it !), so similarly it doesn't constrain the marginal distributions in any way.

As you see, the goal of introducing these $\alpha$-dependent constraints on $P$ is not to make sure that $P$ lies in $U(r,c)$, but rather to add some *regularization* to the problem of interest (which is computing the Sinkhorn distance $d_{M,\alpha}(r,c) := \inf_{P\in U_\alpha(r,c)} \langle P,M\rangle$) and make it more computationally tractable. By letting $\alpha\to 0$, the set $U_\alpha(r,c)$ becomes very small and the distance is easily computed, while letting $\alpha \to \infty$ recovers the set of all possible pairings $U(r,c)$. There is thus some tradeoff between numerical efficiency and accuracy, as always.

- Lastly, you ask

> [...] so what does it mean to have an outer product of two distributions?

In the setting of this paper, probability distributions are represented as "histogram" vectors, i.e. elements $\pi \in \mathbb R^d $ such that $\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_d \ge 0$ and $\sum_{1\le i \le d} \pi_i = 1$. It is not hard to see that this indeed defines a probability distribution on $\{1,\ldots,d\} $ (for instance, the probability distribution "histogram" of a fair dice on $\{1,\ldots,6\}  $ would be given by the vector $(1/6,\ldots,1/6)^T \in \mathbb R^6 $). It may seem overly restrictive to limit ourselves to finitely supported distributions, but this already covers a wide range of applications, as the paper's popularity suggests.

Once you see that the vectors $r$ and $c$ respectively represent probability distributions on $\{1,\ldots,d\}$, you should be able to see that their [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) $rc^T$ represents the joint distribution of the random vector $(X,Y)$, where $X\sim r$, $Y\sim c$, and $X$ and $Y$ are **independent** (you should definitely prove it if it's not clear). In a sense, this is the most "trivial" joint distribution $(X,Y)$ could have given that its marginals are $r$ and $c$. Notice here that due to the identity $h(rc^T) = h(r) + h(c)$, $rc^T$ is an element of $U_\alpha(r,c)$ for *all* $\alpha \ge 0$, hence these sets are never empty and the optimization problem is always well defined.

Hope that helps !